# Can I use the bounding coordinates of a coordinate system to determine the coordinate system for undefined coordinate values?

Tags: coordinate-system, extents

I have a table with coordinates that are undefined, but I know they could be in several different state plane zones/datums. I am thinking I can possibly use coordinate ranges to assign the coordinate system to each record. The state plane zones are based on county boundaries, and so I created several different layers of the counties in the the different zones and datums (and units), then calculated the X and Y max and min. I tried to use these values to see if the X and Y values in the table fell within these ranges but many seem to overlap and I am not getting correct results. I think it is mainly an issue when comparing systems in different units. I am wondering if there is another, better way to do this. Does anyone have suggestions?

Comment: No, extents are somewhat arbitrary.  Consider UTM projections.  Each zone has the same coordinates but they are located in different places.  Worse yet, a place could have different coordinate values in neighboring zones.  Furthermore, the projection definition can include a false origin or other set of offsets. The only reliable way to determine coordinate system is to track it from origin (usually via .prj file or other metadata).

Comment: thanks for the reply. Of course that information is not available for the data I have so I am trying to find any other way to determine the system. It seems like I will not be able to get accurate results for all data.

Comment: If you have a reasonable suspicion, and data which correlates, you might be able to determine coordsys by manual review, but sometimes you have to abandon data without a chain of custody.  Coordinate systems have been regularly collected as part of spatial dataset metadata for over 20 years -- any datasets without metadata are of questionable merit.